# Why strcmp is failing?

Tags: c, string, codeblocks

I am really sorry to ask this question in this portal. Because it may be a silly problem. But, I am struggling to find out why `strcmp` is not working?
I did write my own `strcmp` also and I found out `s1` and `rev` are not same as `rev` is holding some garbage. please help me where is it going wrong?

```
void main()
{
int i,j;
 char rev[5];
 char s1[5]= "madam";
 for(i=strlen(s1)-1, j = 0; i>=0; j++, i--)
 {
  rev[j]=s1[i];
 }
 puts(rev);
 printf("\n");
 puts(s1);
if(strcmp(rev,s1) == 0)
{
printf("Palindrome!!! \n");

}
}
```

In stead of `strcmp(rev, s1)` I wote my own `i_strcmp(rev, s1)`.

```
int i_strcmp(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s1[i] && s2[i]; ++i)
    {
        /* If characters are same or inverting the 6th bit makes them same */
        if (s1[i] == s2[i] || (s1[i] ^ 32) == s2[i])
           continue;
        else
           break;
    }

    /* Compare the last (or first mismatching in case of not same) characters */
    if (s1[i] == s2[i])
        return 0;
    if ((s1[i]|32) < (s2[i]|32)) //Set the 6th bit in both, then compare
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

But still it is not working, and I tried to debug it, and found some garbage value in rev. But when I am printing the string to console it is giving correct output to the console.

Comment: Your strings are not zero-terminated. `strcmp` can only work on zero-terminated strings. Note that you must allocate space for 6 chars in oder to hold a five-character string.

Comment: Two things to note about your `i_strcmp`: 1) the built-in functions often use some clever platform-specific optimizations so will often be faster, and 2) tweaking bit 6 works for plain old ASCII but may fail on international text with other encodings ("ANSI" code pages or UTF-8 for instance.)

Comment: Actually I'm surprised that the compiler isn't warning about you trying to initialize an array of size 5 with 6 values. It's something that should be obvious to the compiler. Or is emitting a warning, and you've just ignored it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with strlen and then strcmp .

All string based functions are based on the null terminating character in C.So, your s1 has no ( null character ) so strlen would not work properly.

For example check this program :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

int main()

{  char a[7]="wwwwwww"; /* --------->No space reserved for NUL. */

    printf("%d",strlen(a));

}
```

Output is 10. Strlen gives incorrect result since you didn't give it its '\0'.

Comment: As a solution I was aying to make s1's size 6.Not in the above program.It was meant to show something else.

Comment: The `10` might due to the fact that the code misses `strlen()`'s prototype, typically from `<string.h>`.

Comment: Also, in case you should have included the correct prototypw for `strlen()`. The conversion modifier shall be `"%zu"` as `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: Sry, for having edited you r answer. I seemed to have misunderstood your 1st comment. However initialisation of `a` is perfectly valid. The `0`-terminator is implicitly added by the compiler and there is room for: it namely `a[6]`, the 7th element of `a`.

Comment: I dont understand the downvote. Please tell me why ?I fed a 7 chars, it has 7 size so no null will be there ?

Comment: I should really think about getting glasses as I read **6** characters. Perhaps `w` isn't the best example character for this .... `"1234567" would indeed have been more obvious. However, sry again. The other two issues are clear, aren't they.

Comment: But I cannot resist continue nitpicking. The `0`-terminator is not a `NULL` but a `NUL` aka `'\0'`. `NULL` is something different `((void*) 0)`.

Comment: Yes the NULL point was wrong but 10 is not due to string.h absence.NULL character is generally, as little as I have read, used for '\0'.Is it wrong ?As for strlen, I learnt What u said, I used %d which worked but as you said isn't correct.

Comment: Above somebody said zero terminated string with 5 upvotes ?? Isn't that wrong to say too?

Answer (score 7):

All functions like `strlen`, `strcmp` need strings with \x00 at the end. Your arrays don't have room for that (5 characters). With your own `strcmp` version you're too relying on the \x00 limitter which most probably doesn't exist.

You could use `strncmp` instead. Or have larger arrays.